# Google Cloud Services Intermittent Content Security Policy Issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a static web site hosted in a google-storage bucket that I serve up via the Google Platform.

This site has been running with no problems for about 6 months but over the last month I have had intermittent problems with it not loading style sheets and scripts due to "Content Security" issues - this results in just the text of the main page appearing the browser with no style and no (Javascript based) functionality. By intermittent I mean it works OK for a couple of hours and then it fails for a couple of hours.

There is no "web server" for this service as such as I am just serving up static pages from a bucket - I understand that Google must have their own server that handles this though. The failures occur no matter what browser the user is using and clearing the browser cache does not help so this issue is at the Google server end.

Checking the developer console in the browser I can see the following issues for all stylesheets, scripts and fonts that the web page uses:

> ```
> > Refused to load the stylesheet XXXXXXX because it violates the
> > following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'".
> > Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is
> > used as a fallback.
> ```

I think I have got my Content Security settings correct:

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
         default-src 'self'; 
         img-src 'self'
            https://syndication.twitter.com;
         font-src 'self'    
            https://use.fontawesome.com
            https://fonts.gstatic.com
            https://fonts.googleapis.com;
         script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
            https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com 
            https://connect.facebook.net
            https://platform.twitter.com
            https://code.jquery.com
            https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com; 
         style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
            https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com 
            https://use.fontawesome.com 
            https://fonts.googleapis.com;
         frame-src 'self'   
            https://www.facebook.com
            https://connect.facebook.net
            https://platform.twitter.com
            https://www.youtube.com;
   ">
```

These are the links that fail, each 'external' one includes signing with the imports to ensure that the "real" thing is loaded.

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong or offer any advice on how to get this working consistently?

Comment: Are you still experiencing the issue? I encountered the same problem, seems like due to a JavaScript url that is being used in a inline <Script>.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately at the moment setting up that CSP header that way is not possible on website buckets, as because the webserver used by Cloud storage for website buckets may be adding a default value for your website.

There's a Feature request [for this](https://issuetracker.google.com/36427250), but it seems it's been a while since the last update.

You could give it a try to App engine standard if you need to serve your page without these issues (you could even apply for the [Always Free Tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free))

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, I'd not seen that feature request/issue before and that was useful. However the issue is intermittent - if the CSP header was wrong or not used in favour of one the webserver replaces it with, wouldn't this issue occur every time? The web site is on https://www.visionfutsal.com/ if you want to take a look.

Comment: oh, I was able to see your webpage and noticed some inline styles and scripts, which would cause this kind of messages, so the browser would ban these styles and scripts automatically in order to prevent any attack you can see more about this here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/#inline-code-considered-harmful, also if you agree I can edit my answer and include this information

Comment: @chinoche Can you explain why it happens intermittently? To me it looks like a bug with browser, since it doesn't happen consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is related, but I am also having problems with loading Firebase storage links, which is in the form of https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket-name/folder-name/folder-name/file?other-query-params-because-sign-url

I've been searching high and low for answers but still can't find a proper solution. If someone can point out what's wrong and the solution for it, that would be great, thanks.